# jQuery - Printing and previewing a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the jQuery print preview plugin (https://github.com/etimbo/jquery-print-preview-plugin) to add some extra functionality to the print ability.

The issue is instead of printing the entire page, I just need a small printable area to be displayed. I believe the only relevant code to this is. My first thought was to change all instances of 'body' to printableArea but had no luck in displaying anything. Any ideas?

```
 // The frame lives
            for (var i=0; i < window.frames.length; i++) {
                if (window.frames[i].name == "print-frame") {    
                    var print_frame_ref = window.frames[i].document;
                    break;
                }
            }
            print_frame_ref.open();
            print_frame_ref.write('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">' +
                '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">' + 
                '<head><title>' + document.title + '</title></head>' +
                '<body></body>' +
                '</html>');
            print_frame_ref.close();

    // Grab contents and apply stylesheet
    var $iframe_head = $('head link[media*=print], head link[media=all]').clone(),
        $iframe_body = $('body > *:not(#print-modal):not(script)').clone();
    $iframe_head.each(function() {
        $(this).attr('media', 'all');
    });
    if (!$.browser.msie && !($.browser.version < 7) ) {
        $('head', print_frame_ref).append($iframe_head);
        $('body', print_frame_ref).append($iframe_body);
    }
    else {
        $('body > *:not(#print-modal):not(script)').clone().each(function() {
        $('body', print_frame_ref).append(this.outerHTML);
        });
        $('head link[media*=print], head link[media=all]').each(function() {
        $('head', print_frame_ref).append($(this).clone().attr('media', 'all')[0].outerHTML);
        });
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="printableArea" style="display:block;">
   <h1>content</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your selectors:

```
 var $iframe_head = $('head link[media*=print], head link[media=all]').clone(),
 $iframe_body = $('body > *:not(#print-modal):not(script)').clone();
```

So change:

```
'body > *:not(#print-modal):not(script)'
```

to select the div instead by using a different selector. Something like `'.myClass'` or`'#myId'` should do.

**note**

this may also need to be altered at the start of your else statement.

Comment: I gave that a shot but it's not displaying anything in the modal box. That was my first thought to change to #printableArea (  $iframe_body = $('#printableArea').clone();) but it is not displaying. I've made an edit to the post describing more of what's going on.

Comment: No errors in the console. The only other instance of body I can find is in a disable scrolling function. "  $('body').css({overflowY: 'hidden', height: '100%'});" I can't see this breaking it though.

Comment: Made a rookie mistake and encountered a caching issue. This was indeed the correct answer!

Comment: @Alex: Glad you got it sorted. I was looking through that plugin and couldn't see any reason why this wouldn't work. :)